# Check if single() LINQ return NULL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that should return either a single result or not results. I call `Single()` to get the result like this:

```
var propertyDataSource = (from x in myCollection
                          where SomeCondition(x)
                          select x).Single();
```

This works okay when my query has a single result, but if there are no results it throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message *Sequence contains no elements*.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

[`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws an exception when the enumeration does not contain exactly one element, [`SingleOrDefault<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is `null` for reference types) when called on empty enumerations instead. Note that both will throw if there is more than one element in the enumeration.

Answer (score 8):

By design, [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw an exception when the sequence is empty. Use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to return `null` when your sequence is empty.

Answer (score 8):

`.SingleOrDefault()` will return the single matching object or the default value (which is `null` for reference types). You will have to handle the `null` case yourself though because you'll end up with a `NullReferenceException` pretty quickly.

As a side note, you should use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0` to avoid iterating over your entire dataset when using `IEnumerable`s.

Answer (score 6):

`.FirstOrDefault()` returns null (or default of the type) if nothing exists (no match is found), `.Single()` will expect exactly one match. `.SingleOrDefault()` will return null (or default of the type) if nothing exists but will throw exception if you have more than one match.